# Optimize Conditional while loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a huge dataframe in python +7mil rows. My general problem is that I need to run over a column and make a new 'numer' every time I see a '#' in that column. So the first time I see a # I overwrite it with 1 and drop this row, then I  continue in the next row with the same number until I see again a '#' and i procede that.

I already have some code in place, but at it is a loop it is super slow!

```
i=0
j=0
while i <len(data):    
    if  data.iloc[i][0] == '#':
        j=j+1
        data = data.drop(data.index[i])                   
    else:   
        data.iloc[i][0] = j
    i=i+1
return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
m = (data.iloc[:, 0] == '#')
data.iloc[:, 0] = m.cumsum()
data.drop(m.index[m], inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is amazing the new operation Needs `0.15599989891052246' and the old one was '1951.7464001178741`